# Meteor Call object is different to the received Meteor Method object

Tags: javascript, typescript, meteor

I'm sending an object from the client to the server using a Meteor Call and Meteor method.

When the object is received in the `Method` it looks different. It is nested within the `giftList`

**Meteor Call - JSON.stringify**

```
{"personName":"Default person name","username":"","gifts":[]}
```

**Meteor Method**

```
{"giftList":{"personName":"Default person name","username":"","gifts":[]}}
```

**Meteor Call Code**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(giftList))  // {"personName":"Default person name","username":"","gifts":[]}

Meteor.call("addGiftList", {giftList}, (err: any, res) => {});
```

**Meteor Method code**

```
Meteor.methods({
    "addGiftList": function (giftList: GiftList): void {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(giftList))  // {"giftList":{"personName":"Default person name","username":"","gifts":[]}}
        return GiftListCollectionManager.getInstance().insert(giftList);
    }
});
```

**GiftList**

```
export class GiftList {

    personName: string = "";

    username: string = "";

    gifts: Gift[] = [];
}
```

Why is the received object different and what is the correct method of handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is your way of passing `giftList` to Meteor.call. Passing in `{giftList}` is shorthand for `{ giftList: giftList }`.

Try the following:

```
Meteor.call("addGiftList", giftList, (err: any, res) => {});
```